# TLS/SSL on http (80) with STARTTLS

Tags: ssl, http, starttls

I'm researching the reason why TLS/SSL is not using over HTTP. Other protocols, such as SMTP, POP3, FTP, etc can be used on SSL ports (SMTP**S**, POP3**S**, FTP**S**) for the first way, and the second way is to use STARTTLS option in the current port with the extension ([SMTP example](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3207))
There is a popular way to use the second way (STARTTLS) on email protocols, but why is http not using STARTTLS?
I found [RFC TLS within HTTP/1.1](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2817.txt), but it is not using nowadays (or maybe i havent seen yet)

Comment: HTTP already have 3xx redirects to upgrade to HTTPS. Why would you add STARTTLS if you already have a convenient way to upgrade embedded in your protocol?

Comment: Starting with a plaintext protocol and then upgrade to TLS means there is plenty of time for attacking the connection. The smaller the attack surface the smaller chance for an successful attack. Therefore STARTTLS protocols are more and more replaced by real TLS protected connections.

Answer (score 3):

One purpose of the *Upgrade mechanism* in [RFC 2817](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2817#section-1) was the provide a *virtual hosting* mechanism for HTTP with TLS as the situation was back in 2000:

> The Upgrade mechanism also solves the "virtual hosting" problem.
> Rather than allocating multiple IP addresses to a single host, an
> HTTP/1.1 server will use the Host: header to disambiguate the
> intended web service. As HTTP/1.1 usage has grown more prevalent,
> more ISPs are offering name-based virtual hosting, thus delaying IP
> address space exhaustion.

The *Server Name Indication* (SNI; [RFC 3546, 3.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3546#section-3.1)) gave a better solution to this problem in 2003 – the one still in use – so there has not been need for this anymore. The `Upgrade` header is still alive but used for different purposes like switching from HTTP/1.1 to HTTP/2.0 ([RFC 7230, 6.7](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230#section-6.7)).

The HTTP protocol also has the `Location` header ([RFC 7231, 7.1.2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-7.1.2)) with the related response codes, making it easy to redirect the client to another scheme, host and port, unlike the protocols that were using `STARTTLS`.

Also notice that using `STARTTLS` was not something good and desirable and something that should be adopted by more protocols. In fact, [RFC 8314](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8314) now obsoletes the cleartext protocols for email submission and access, leaving MTA-to-MTA SMTP the only email protocol where `STARTTLS` should be used. From [section 3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8314#section-3):

> – – Although this mechanism has been deployed, an alternate mechanism
> where TLS is negotiated immediately at connection start on a
> separate port (referred to in this document as "Implicit TLS") has
> been deployed more successfully.  To encourage more widespread use of
> TLS and to also encourage greater consistency regarding how TLS is
> used, this specification now recommends the use of Implicit TLS for
> POP, IMAP, SMTP Submission, and all other protocols used between an
> MUA and an MSP.

Answer (score 1):

One reason might be that an additional STARTTLS would add more overhead since an additional round trip (request + response) is needed. The time from connection start to response is fairly critical with HTTP though and lots of optimizations where done to reduce this time, like shorter TLS handshake or different protocols like QUIC. Adding something like STARTTLS would increase the time instead and thus is not a good idea.